# not able to increase width of dynamically created label in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a problem and it is that i am trying to create label dynamically and set text of a textarea but the problem is that i am not able to increase the size of the label dynamically through javascript, i've posted both html and javascript code below :-

javascript

```
function createLabel(){
    var lbl = document.createElement("label");
    lbl.id = "label2";
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var lblText = document.getElementById("postbox").value;
    lbl.innerHTML = lblText;
    lbl.style.display = "block";
    tr.appendChild(lbl);
    tr.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("postTd").appendChild(tr);
    $("#label2").css("width", "50px;")
}
```

html :-

```
<div id="wrapper">
<a href="profile.php"><label id="label1" style="cursor:pointer;"><?php echo user_details('username'); ?></label></a>
<textarea id="postbox" rows="4" style="position: absolute; resize:none; margin-left:450px; margin-top:70px;" cols="70"></textarea>
<input type="submit" onclick="createLabel()" value="Post" style="position: absolute; margin-top:150px; margin-left:990px;" name="submit" />
<div id="hrln1" style="position:absolute; margin-top:150px; width:1050px; margin-left:0px;"><hr /></div>
<div id="postContainer">

    <table id="postTable">
    <td id="postTd">

    </td>        
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: first of all sir can you guide me how should i post html code...

Comment: hey @tomalak can u please please please tell me how did u do that..

Comment: check this for editing the question format http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Why are you trying to append a label to a table row? A label can't be a child element of a tr element.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the display mode of the label to `inline`, so it will ignore any width you set on it (whether it is set with script or CSS)

For elements to obey width correctly they must be set to `display:block` or `display:inline-block`